# Question about order of variable and pathname expansion in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting, variable

Bash expands variables before expanding pathnames (globbing). Assuming that it did it the other way round (i.e. expand pathnames before expanding variables), is it possible to write a bash script that uses both variable expansion and path expansion, such that the result is the same irrespective of the order of expansion.

I have come up with the following simple bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a variable called myvar1
myvar1=~
echo $myvar1

# Use both path expansion and variable expansion with the ls command
# Assuming the variable was expanded first, the out should be the same as if the path was expanded first. Is my assumption correct?
ls $myvar1/*.txt
```

Can someone verify that my script answers the question satisfactorily?

Comment: Not quite: consider a directory containing a file called `$myvar1`, and you do `ls *`. This will expand to potentially many files, one of which is `$myvar1`. Then (in this hypothetical world) this variable will be expanded to `~` and you will see the contents of your home directory (assuming `~` expansion still occurs after that, otherwise it will attempt to show a file literally called `~`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls $myvar1/*.txt
```

If pathnames were expanded before variables, this would look for filenames matching `*.txt` in a directory called `$myvar1`, which you probably wouldn't have. After that, it would expand `$myvar1` to the path to your home directory, leaving `/home/username/*.txt`, which is not the same as expanding the path first and then looking for filenames ending in `.txt` in the home directory.

In general, since file names can contain `$` signs, I think the order of expansion will always matter. Consider any script using a glob like `*` in a directory containing a file called `$PATH`.

The opposite, variables containing glob characters, is easier to work around, since you control the values of your variables.